# Can this be namespace or type aliased?

Tags: c#, alias, using

I'm working in a C# program now where there is a class ("GlobalConstants") of just global constants for things like error messages and return values.   Most of these are in big enumerated types, so there are lots of places in the code where I have to type or read lines that look like this . . .

```
case GlobalConstants.SubunitAssemblyFailureEnums.FOD_ERROR:
```

so I'd love to be able to abbreviate the qualifier with something short, so it's . . .

```
case gsf.FOD_ERROR:
```

Is there a way to do this with namespace or type aliasing in C#?   I tried

```
using gsf = GlobalConstants.SubunitAssemblyFailureEnums;
```

... but the compiler just said  "GlobalConstants.SubunitAssemblyFailureEnums is a 'type' which is not valid in the given context"

***Edit:*
The Answer** . . . was that my placement was wrong.    My file is structured like this . . .

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace  ****
{

    class ****
    {
        method*** {   }

        method*** {   }

       ... etc...


    } //end class
} // end namespace
```

The first place I tried it was above the namespace directive with the other "using"s.   The compiler didn't like that.     Then I tried it inside my class, and it didn't like that either.  But I got it to work just fine **between** the namespace directive and the class definition

Comment: Ew.  Whose idea was `GlobalConstants` and are they still employed?

Comment: No, they're not 8-)   Unfortunately the class is thousands of lines long by now so I doubt it will ever get re-architected.

Comment: For your `using` attempt, did you place it at the top of the file? That should work.

Comment: Where exactly is your `using` directive located? And is `GlobalConstants.SubunitAssemblyFailureEnums` the full namespace plus type name?

Comment: Re: your last edit - You _can_ do it outside the namespace but you'd need to include the namespace that the class is is.  It's working inside the namespace because the class in in the same namespace as your `using` statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `using` statement should work provided you include the entire namespace that `GlobalConstants` is in - for example, to add an alias for `DayOfWeek` use:

```
using dow = System.DayOfWeek;
```

Did you put it at the top of the file?  Maybe it thinks you're trying to use the `using()` pattern for a disposable object

Comment: Actually D Stanley had the answer.   I didn't have it at the VERY top of my file - I had it inside my class definition. It turns out to work just fine if I have it BETWEEN the namespace directive and the class definition.   There are lots of places on the web that talk about aliasing and most of them don't mention how important placement of it is.  I'll update my question to reflect the answer.